# How to postpone the set up of a conditional?

Tags: conditionals

I'm about to produce a series of assessment texts. Some of these assessments have annexes, others don't. I would like to be able to define a specific class, like this :

```
\documentclass{myexam}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\section{Easy steps}
\section{Advanced steps}
\section*{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

And the `\frontmatter` macro should print something like :

> This text consists of 5 pages plus an appendix of 2 pages.

while, in absence of appendix, it should print like :

> This text consists of 5 pages.

I tried to use labels together with a conditional (`\newif\ifannex` and so on), but it doesn't seem to work.
Ideas ?

Comment: More details : I had the idea of putting a `\label{append}` within the appendix (easy) and to define in the preamble a macro like this : `\def\apndx{\ref{append}}`. When the appendix is present, `\apndx` gets a value, fine. Else the compiler sends a warning (normal) and `\apndx` seems to get the value ?? and not `\relax`.

Comment: What did you try to do? `\ref` and `\label` need a second compilation run.

Comment: Of course, twice (or more) !

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `lastpage` and `refcount` packages, but modifying the way you introduce your appendix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lastpage,refcount}

\newcommand{\frontmatter}{%
  % Whatever you need to put at the beginning
  \computepages
  This text consists of \pageorpages{\textpages}%
  \ifannex
    \ plus an appendix of \pageorpages{\appendixpages}%
  \fi
  .%
}
\newcommand\pageorpages[1]{#1~page\ifnum#1=1 \else s\fi}
% Just in case we need them
\newcommand\textpages{0}
\newcommand\appendixpages{0}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\computepages}{%
  \ifannex
    \edef\textpages{\number\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{annexstart}-1\relax}%
    \edef\appendixpages{\number\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}-\getpagerefnumber{annexstart}+1\relax}%
  \else
    \edef\textpages{\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}}%
  \fi
}

\newif\ifannex
\newcommand{\annex}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\noexpand\global\noexpand\annextrue}%
  \section*{#1}%
  \label{annexstart}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\section{Easy steps}

\newpage
\section{Advanced steps}

\newpage
\annex{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

This correctly shows

> This text consists of 2 pages plus an appendix of 1 page.

while, if the `\annex` line is commented out, the output is

> This text consists of 2 pages.

Of course, a couple of compilations are needed for the numbers to synchronize.

Comment: Great ! I'll check this tomorrow. Anyway, I was convinced it was necessary to write and read directly to the aux file, that was the trick you just implemented. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any drawback in using something like `\ifx\r@annexstart\@undefined` (as I did in my humble attempt) to check if `\annex` is called, aside from the fact that the user may use the label without `\annex`? `\label{annexstart}` writes to `.aux` anyway, why not use it?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Why did you delete the answer? Your method is good, but I prefer to state explicitly what I want, that's all.

Comment: I did not know of `refcount`, otherwise I would've tried to use `\numexpr`, too. (And would have avoided running into problems with `hyperref` and the like.)

Answer (score 3):

This solution uses `\ztotpages` of package `zref`'s module `zref-totpages` for the number of total pages.
This number does not depend on the page numbering scheme. The question mentioned `\frontmatter`. Usually this uses `\pagenumbering{roman}` and a following `\mainmatter` uses `\pagenumbering{arabic}` with resetting the page counter. The label `LastPage` of package `lastpage` will not see the pages before `\mainmatter`.

However it is not clear, on which class `myexam` is based. The use of `\section` would assume a `article` based class, but that does not provide `\frontmatter`. Classes with
`\frontmatter` would use `\chapter`. Therefore the solution defines `\frontmatter` if
it is not given, otherwise `\frontmatter` is extended to print the additional text.

The appendix is detected by the presence of `zref` label `StartAppendix`. For convenience the label setting and `\section*{Appendix}` is put into macro `\Appendix`. If the label is detected, then the number of appendix pages is added to the text.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{zref-totpages}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\AppendixStartLabel}{%
  \@bsphack
    \zref@labelbyprops{StartAppendix}{abspage}%
    \zref@refused{StartAppendix}%
  \@esphack
}
\newcommand*{\printpages}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1%
    \textbf{??}~pages%
  \or
    1~page%
  \else
    \number#1~pages%
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\FrontmatterText}{%
  \noindent
  This text consists of \printpages{\ztotpages}%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{StartAppendix}{%
  }{%
    \newcommand*{\appendix@pages}{}%
    \edef\appendix@pages{%
      \numexpr\zref@extractdefault{LastPage}{abspage}{0}%
      -\zref@extractdefault{StartAppendix}{abspage}{0}%
      +1%
    }%
    \space including an appendix of \printpages{\appendix@pages}%
  }%
  .\par
}
\@ifundefined{frontmatter}{%
  \newcommand*{\frontmatter}{%
    \clearpage
    \FrontmatterText
  }%
}{%
  \g@addto@macro\frontmatter{\FrontmatterText}%
}
\newcommand{\Appendix}{%
  \clearpage
  \section*{\appendixname}%
  \AppendixStartLabel
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\section{Easy steps}
\section{Advanced steps}
\Appendix
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Hello, I think this is the best solution (in my opinion), quite simple and elegant.

Comment: Works fine; I just think there is a minor error, e.g. the line `\space plus an appendix of \printpages{\appendix@pages}%` should be  `\space including an appendix of \printpages{\appendix@pages}%` isn't it ?

Comment: @rcabane You are right, I had used the wording of the question, but with a different meaning of "text". Getting the pages without the appendix is left as exercise for the reader (not too difficult with `\numexpr`, for example).

Answer (score 2):

## Better solution

After [finding out about `refcount`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77652/16595) we can skip the calculations with counters (and avoid running into problems with `hyperref` and other packages that redefine `\ref` so that it is more than just some digits).

I have now borrowed the idea of egreg to outsource the calculations. It makes a much cleaner code.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcounter{tempcounter}

\newcommand*{\pageorpages}[1]{#1~page\ifnum#1=1 \else s\fi}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textpages}{%Calculation of _text_ pages
  \ifx\r@DontYouDareUseThisLabelApndxStart\@undefined% without appendix
    \number\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}+1-\getpagerefnumber{FirstTextPage}\relax
  \else % with appendix
    \number\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{DontYouDareUseThisLabelApndxStart}-\getpagerefnumber{FirstTextPage}\relax
  \fi%
}

\newcommand*{\apndxpages}{% Calculation of _appendix_ pages.
\ifx\r@DontYouDareUseThisLabelApndxStart\@undefined0\else % to prevent errors if this is called accidently
  \number\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}-\getpagerefnumber{DontYouDareUseThisLabelApndxStart}+1\relax
\fi
}

\newcommand*{\howmanypages}{% \frontmatter is already defined in some classes
  The following text consists of \pageorpages{\textpages}%
  \ifx\r@DontYouDareUseThisLabelApndxStart\@undefined\else % with appendix
    \space plus an appendix of \pageorpages{\apndxpages}%
  \fi.
  \clearpage % again, no sketchy calculations
  \label{FirstTextPage}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\apndx}{
  \clearpage
  \section*{Appendix}
  \label{DontYouDareUseThisLabelApndxStart} % and I mean it!
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\howmanypages
\section{Easy steps}
\lipsum
\section{Advanced steps}
\lipsum
\apndx
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

## Bad Solution (breaks with `hyperref` and what not)

With the use of one auxiliary counter you can accomplish something like this very easily.

#### `\apndx`

The macro `apndx` uses a `\clearpage` so that it actually starts on an own page. Otherwise the calculation may be *sketchy*.
The label `apndxstart` is not only used to get the actual page number, but also to check if there is even an appendix (via the macro `\r@apndxstart`).

#### `\howmanypages`

This macro checks whether a appendix is used:

```
\ifx\r@apndxstart\@undefined
```

and then proceed to calculate the actual page numbers.

#### `lastpage` package

The `lastpage` packages is used to get the last page number (with or without appendix).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\newcounter{tempcounter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\howmanypages}{% \frontmatter is already defined in some classes
  \ifx\r@apndxstart\@undefined % without appendix
    \setcounter{tempcounter}{\pageref{LastPage}}
    \addtocounter{tempcounter}{1}
  \else% with appendix
    \setcounter{tempcounter}{\pageref{apndxstart}}%
  \fi%
  \addtocounter{tempcounter}{-\pageref{FirstPage}}
  This text consists of \thetempcounter{} page\ifnum\thetempcounter=1\else s\fi
  \ifx\r@apndxstart\@undefined % without appendix
    .
  \else % with appendix
    \setcounter{tempcounter}{\pageref{LastPage}}%
    \addtocounter{tempcounter}{-\pageref{apndxstart}}%
    \addtocounter{tempcounter}{1}%
    \space plus an appendix of \thetempcounter{} page\ifnum\thetempcounter=1\else s\fi.
  \fi
  \label{FirstPage}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\apndx}{
  \clearpage
  \section*{Appendix}
  \label{apndxstart}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\howmanypages
\section{Easy steps}
\lipsum
\section{Advanced steps}
\lipsum
\apndx
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, this works but produces an error at the first compiler pass.

Comment: @rcabane Which error do you get? I only get a warning encouraging me to rerun to get the references right. (And do not use the “Bad Solution”.)

Comment: Oh it could be that I mistakenly borrowed my file from the bad solution, not from the good one. I got : `No file apndx3.aux.
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.36 \howmanypages`

Comment: @rcabane This only happens with the “Bad Solution” (by the way, a second run helps to get it work). But as I said, my other solution won't have that problem. It does get the page number in a much cleaner and safer way.